# Can someone confirm the stateful-ness of metrics in tf.keras (tensorflow-2)?

Tags: metrics, tf.keras, stateful

I am new to tensorflow and trying to re-write some of the usual metrics such as accuracy and f1, but on a per-class basis, i.e. if my data has 3 classes A, B, C, what are the accuracies, f1 s etc for A, B and C separately. My model and training scripts etc are almost entirely defined in tf.keras. But since I'm a little late to the party, I'm not sure if the metrics: both built in ones such as tf.keras.Metric.TruePositives for instance or the general tf.keras.Metric are stateful, i.e. the metric will *NOT* be averaged over batches? I have read and re-read too many github and stack-overflow issues over keras metrics being non-stateful in the past and so can't seem to wrap my head around whether I can trust tf.keras.Metric in tensorflow-2 and start subclassing it, or do something else. 
Any insight would be great. (A definitive pointer to a release update where this is written explicitly would be a plus!!)

Thanks,
Tanmoy